# Powershell script to add CSv

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

How to fetch data from CSv to PowerShell?

Comment: Are you saying, the CSV that holds the 'IP, hostname and zone information' is a different CSV than what you have here: '$Csv = Import-Csv .\Test.csv'

Comment: No, that's the same CSv, actually, Test.csv hold the information IP, hostname, and zone. I want the script to look into hostname, IP, and Zone column and add line by line in my firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on this...

> No, that's the same CSv, actually, Test.csv hold the information IP,
>   hostname, and zone. I want the script to look into hostname, IP, and
>   Zone column and add line by line in my firewall.

Your actions should be inside that loop, because as it stands now, that loop is not doing anything for your cause other than listing what is in the CSV file.

With that layout you show, that is space delimited file, not the default comma separate CSV. So, you have to specify that space as a delimiter or you won't get what you'd expect, column-wise.

```
# Assign and display the dataset from the data source
($Csv = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Scripts\test.csv' -Delimiter ' ')

# Results

NEW_HOSTNAME NEW_IP_ADDRESS ZONE
------------ -------------- ----
WEBSERVER_01 1.1.1.1        DMZ 
SQLSERVER_01 5.5.5.5        SQL

ForEach($lol in $Csv)
{
    # Your do something code goes here for each item to be processed
    $lol.NEW_HOSTNAME
}
```